# Display not clear after setup XFCE

Tags: server, ssh, xfce, xrdp

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu Linux. I have server running in ssh. But now, I want setup UI for server and can remove to server by remote desktop. 
I setup xfce (include xrdp). But the display after setup is not clear. (detailed in the image).
I have reinstall, remove and setup again but it not correct.
Hope everyone can help me solving this problem.

[image: detail of error]

Comment: I solved this problem. I change the color connect from client to 16 bpp.

Comment: Then the best course of action is to answer your own question and then accept the answer in two days, this way this doesn'T linger here as unanswered question.